# how to obtain blocks of correlated variables within corrplot heatmap in r

Tags: r

I have several variables (e.g., 2000) CPGs and I would want to obtain the block or cluster of variables that are correlated within corrplot/heatmap at a certain threshold, say 0.3. I have attached a correlation plot for a few of the CPGs. Is there a function in r to execute this? Is there any way to go about this in R? Thanks for your help!
R[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "obtain the block"? Print out correlations as numbers in range [-0.3,0.3]? Only plot these in a heatmap? Mark them in a plot among all others?

Comment: @Andre. What I mean by block is essentially cluster. In particular, what I seek to find is to obtain various clusters (with each cluster corresponding to a group of variables that are correlated) based on the heatmap at a certain threshold. My interest is to group these large sets of CpGs into clusters and fit a model with each set of variables within the different clusters. For e.g., the variables (CpGs); "cg04513038",  "cg09448654", "cg24217729",  "cg07901199", and  "cg21598631" could form one cluster which would be used to fit one model.

Comment: The most straight forward way would be to do a hierarchical clustering, then cut the tree at a certain level and then filter by desired name. You can either do that on the whole data set or pre filter the distance calculation.

Comment: Thanks, @Andre but my understanding of clustering is that usually it is performed on the cases. Is it feasible to perform that on the variables?

Comment: Only on the values. Although I don't understand what you mean by cases.

Comment: Cases are more or less the IDs

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to obtain a clustering of the correlations. Using `mtcars` as toy data. You can choose a different number of clusters to adjust their "sensitivity". The more clusters the less members the higher their "sensitivity".

```
library(gplots)

# select 4 clusters
ct <- cutree(hclust(dist(cor(mtcars))), 4)

hm <- heatmap.2(cor(mtcars), trace="none", 
  col=colorRampPalette(c("blue2","white","red2"))(40), 
  breaks=seq(-1,1,length.out=41), RowSideColors=as.character(ct))
```

[image: heatmap of correlations]

You can filter by values afterwards by simply selecting a range from the matrix `hm$carpet`

```
dat <- hm$carpet
dat[dat < .3] <- NA

image(dat, axes=F, col=colorRampPalette(c("blue2","white","red2"))(40),
  breaks=seq(-1,1,length.out=41))
axis(1, at=seq(0,1, length.out=11), labels=rownames(dat), las=2)
```

[image: image of filtered values > .3]